# How do you register a field with React Final Form with MUI TextField?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

I have an MUI TextField (not the mui-rff) that I want to set a touched to when there is an onchange event on the textfield. I tried adding the name attribute to it, but I'm not sure how to register it so Final Form can see that it's been touched.

```
<Form>
  <MyComponent name="hello" />
</Form>

// MyComponent returns a TextField
<TextField name={name} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need an onchange event handler and function for the textfield.